# How to insert new values in MySql tables only those differents from rows that already exists?

Tags: mysql

I have a database1 in one computer and a database2 (mirrror) in another computer.

Db1 is updated. I should update db2 once a week. To do this task I coulde make a dump from db1 e delete and reload de dump in computer 2. But in fact only one table changes data.
Is there a way to insert into this table (in db2) only the new values from db1 ?

Note: I could do thins using php code. But I am trying to know if is there a way to do that directly in mysql.

Comment: This solution should point you in the right direction i think : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956455/mysql-only-insert-new-row-if-combination-of-columns-which-allow-duplicates-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rows that don't exist use an exception join.

```
insert into destinationtable 
select a.* from mytable a exception join destinationtable b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I've fixed the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

yes..use database replication by SQLYog.. using this technique database values from one server to another or one db to another may be transferred or updated. install SQLYog community edition and follow synchronization tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of just INSERT. This will only add rows if they don't already exist.

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html for more info