# MySQL check 2 values already exists before insert

Tags: mysql

My columns are like this. column "a" is primary and auto incremantal.

```
a |  b |  x  |  y
```

When inserting new data, i need to check x and y columns shouldn't be exist together.

To clarify, imagine this row is at database with these values

```
(2, "example.com" , "admin", "123456")
```

I should able to insert both of these columns

```
(3, "example.com" , "user", "123456")
(4, "example2.com" , "admin", "123456")
```

But i shouldn't able to insert this column

```
(5, "example.com" , "admin", "5555555")
```

Because "example.com" and "admin" values already in database on a row. It doesn't matter column "y" is same or not.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to let the database do the work.  Although you can set up a condition within a query, that condition may not be universally true or someone might use another query.

The database can check this with a unique constraint or index.  Actually, the unique constraint is implementing using a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_b_x on t(b, x);
```

(The columns can be in either order.)

The insert would then look like:

```
insert into t(b, x, y)
    values ('example.com', 'admin', '5555555')
    on duplicate key update b = values(b);
```

Note that the auto-incremented value is not included in the update.

The `on duplicate key update` just prevents the `insert` from generating an error.  It is better than `insert ignore` because the latter will ignore *all* errors, and you just want to ignore the one caused by the duplicate key.

Answer (score 3):

Create a composite unique index. This will allow any number of duplicates in the individual fields, but the combination needs to be unique.
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_uq ON tablename (b, x);

...and use INSERT IGNORE to insert if the unique index is not violated. If it is, just ignore the insert.

INSERT IGNORE INTO test (a,b,x,y) VALUES (5, "example.com" , "admin", "5555555");

If you want to insert unless there's a duplicate, and update if there is, you can also use INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;

Ref: [MySQL only insert new row if combination of columns (which allow duplicates) is unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956455/mysql-only-insert-new-row-if-combination-of-columns-which-allow-duplicates-is)